# Git create a subfolder

Tags: java, git, github, directory, bitbucket

I've just started to use Bitbucket, but I've the same problem on Github. I'm using Eclipse with EGit.

My problem is when I commit and push: I don't see directly "src" but there's a folder and it's in: https://bitbucket.org/Knux14/screenup/src/

Instead of having my src folder, I need to click on "ScreenUp" first, and then I can see src. 
Did I make a mistake on pushing?

Comment: What were you expecting to see?

Comment: Directly my src folder, like on other Github/bitbucket : https://github.com/Bukkit/CraftBukkit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply added the folder **containing** your whole project to Git, so now all your stuff is in the subfolder ("ScreenUp").

You can keep using it like this, that's no big problem. But if it bugs you, just remove the repository and remove the project from version control (Google will help), and add it again.